Use "{{flutter_service_worker_version}}" template token instead. // FlutterLoader.load
How can i correct this in index.html in my flutter web app?
"const serviceWorkerVersion = null;"
"_flutter.loader.loadEntrypoint({"
"
Warning: In index.html:37: Local variable for "serviceWorkerVersion" is deprecated. Use "{{flutter_service_worker_version}}" template token instead.
Warning: In index.html:46: "FlutterLoader.loadEntrypoint" is deprecated. Use "FlutterLoader.load" instead.
"


I try to solve the problem with chatgpt but didnt result, please help me:D

Solution for "serviceWorkerVersion" is deprecated
Replace this line in web/index.html:
const serviceWorkerVersion = null;

with:
var serviceWorkerVersion = '{{flutter_service_worker_version}}';


Solution for "FlutterLoader.loadEntrypoint" is deprecated
Replace your script with this:
  <script>
    window.addEventListener('load', function(ev) {
      {{flutter_js}}
      {{flutter_build_config}}
      
      _flutter.loader.load({
        serviceWorker: {
          serviceWorkerVersion: {{flutter_service_worker_version}},
        },
        onEntrypointLoaded: function(engineInitializer) {
          engineInitializer.initializeEngine().then(function(appRunner) {
            if(document.getElementById('splash'))
              document.getElementById('splash').remove();
            appRunner.runApp();
          });
        }
      });
    });
  </script>


With this I solved it
<script>
    // The value below is injected by flutter build, do not touch.

    const serviceWorkerVersion = "{{flutter_service_worker_version}}";
  </script>
  <!-- This script adds the flutter initialization JS code -->
  <script src="flutter.js" defer></script>
</head>
<body>
  <script>
    window.addEventListener('load', function(ev) {
      {{flutter_js}}
      {{flutter_build_config}}
      // Download main.dart.js
      _flutter.loader.load({
        serviceWorker: {
          serviceWorkerVersion: serviceWorkerVersion,
        },
        onEntrypointLoaded: function(engineInitializer) {
          engineInitializer.initializeEngine().then(function(appRunner) {
            appRunner.runApp();
          });
        }
      });
    });
  </script>

